# Connection refused to host: localhost

Tags: java, rmi, connection-refused

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; 
nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Server code:

```
TaxService taxService = new TaxService();
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(8889);
registry.bind("TaxService", taxService);
System.out.println("The server started");
```

Client code:

```
Registry registry = null;
    try {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 8889);
    } catch (RemoteException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ITaxService taxService = null;
    try {
        taxService = (ITaxService) registry.lookup("TaxService");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Did you run the RMI registry?

Comment: Henry, Firstly I executed the server side and it worked and after that when I tried to executed the client side I got this error message. The error came from this line registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 8889);

Comment: (1) Are you installing the RMISecurityManager?  If yes, you may need to tweak the securlty policy to allow connections to localhost:8889 ...  (2) After you start the server, assuming it stays up and running, can you open a second terminal and telnet to localhost 8889 ?  If yes, the server is there, so it's a client issue; if no, then it's a server issue ...

Comment: The error did not come from `getRegistry()`. This method does not perform any network I/O. It came from `lookup()` in the client, or when you called your remote method. Please provide the complete stack trace. And check item A.1 in the RMI FAQ. And state whether the server is running in the same host as the client. And @moilejter The security manager does not cause connection refusals.